# Making sense of Angular filter exceptions

Tags: angularjs, angular-filters

Is it possible to determine where a filter was called from, in case of an exception?

I have a filter that is used in multiple pages, which cause an exception if input parameter is undefined. The stacktrace points to my filter function, which makes it hard to debug from exactly which html file/page it originated.

```js
angular.module('myModule', [])
  .filter('myFilter', function() {
    return function(val) {
      // this fails if val is undefined
      return val.something;
    }
  });
```

My motivation:

I am using a clientside logger which logs to a server backend, so retrieving this information would be very helpful.

Comment: Try to Use or operator on return: returnreturn val.someValueThatMaySometimesBeUndefined || false;

Answer (score 0):

You can achieve this by decorating the exception handler.

```
angular.module('myModule').config([
                              '$provide', function($provide) {

        $provide.decorator("$exceptionHandler", ['$delegate', function($delegate) {
            return function(exception, cause) {
                $delegate(exception, cause);
                console.log(exception.toString());
                console.log(exception.fileName);
                console.log(exception.lineNumber);
            };
        }]);

}]);
```

Comment: I think you are on the right track, but I was unable to get your example working. Here is my attempt: https://jsfiddle.net/w34sx8ou/4/.

In all my attempts, exception.filename and lineNumber are undefined

On a sidenote, the stacktraces provided by angular 1.2 are easier to work with than those provided by 1.4

Comment: I am checking on this.

Comment: In this case, Exception.toString() is the only thing giving appropriate information. I have been using the same in controllers/services/directives and is working fine and all the information is available.